allowing duplicate attribute option values in store Level
Whenever i tried to add duplicate option value in Admin its throws an error like
"The value of Admin must be unique. (AB)" This is Totally fine.

but in storeView duplicated values are allowing is this a Bug or allowing duplicate values in store view is correct? if it okay,, Can anyone Expain why it is okay to save duplicate options in storeView.


In Magento 2, managing attribute options involves configuring the values that customers and administrators see for product attributes. The discrepancy you've observed, where the system allows the same value for "Default Store View" but not for "Is Default Admin," can be explained by understanding the different purposes and constraints of these settings.
Default Store View
Default Store View refers to the display value of an attribute option as seen by the customers on the front end of the store. This is tied to the specific store view and can be customized for different languages or regional settings.
Allows Same Value: Magento allows the same value for different attribute options in the Default Store View because different options might be needed for different contexts or regions but can share the same displayed text. This flexibility supports localization and customization needs.
Is Default Admin
Is Default Admin refers to the internal identifier or default value of an attribute option within the Magento admin panel. This setting is used by the system to distinguish between different attribute options programmatically.
Does Not Allow Same Value: Magento enforces uniqueness for "Is Default Admin" to avoid confusion and potential conflicts within the backend processes. Each attribute option must have a unique identifier to ensure accurate data management and processing.
Reasons for the Difference
1. Data Integrity: Ensuring that "Is Default Admin" values are unique prevents data conflicts and ensures that each attribute option can be distinctly identified in the backend operations.
2. Localization: Allowing duplicate values in the "Default Store View" supports the need for localization, where different regions or languages might use the same text for different attribute options.
3. Backend Processing: The Magento system relies on unique identifiers for backend processing and integrations. Allowing duplicates in "Is Default Admin" would complicate these processes and could lead to errors or data corruption.
Conclusion
The primary reason for this difference is to maintain data integrity and avoid conflicts in backend operations while allowing flexibility and customisation for the front-end display to accommodate different languages and regional requirements.
If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.
Happy Coding

@Chandra Shekhar
Hey,
In Magento 2, by default, it doesn't allow duplicate attribute option values for an attribute at the global level. However, if you need to allow duplicate attribute option values at the store view level, you can achieve this by customizing Magento's attribute option handling.
Thank You!

In attributes, the Admin Value serves as a unique key that must be specified. This value will be visible when the attribute is used in any product, allowing you to identify the default attribute value.
In the default Store View, This value acts as a label, which can be set to any specific or identical label in any store view. Essentially, it functions as a label only.
